# How would you calculate the probability of matching n out of m preselected elements of a set of p elemenets while drawing k?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I thought maybe maybe (m choose n) / (p choose k) but this doesn't really make sense.. No idea which choose to choose.

Example: there are 100 balls in a bucket, numbered. I name 20 of those balls prior to drawing 10 from the bucket. What is the probability that 5 balls out of the 20 I named are among the 10 drawn?

(Bonus question: what is the probability of at least 5 being among the drawn?)

How would I get to the answer conclusively?

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen oh nice, so all m are just successes and p-m the failures, that works I guess, thanks